# Monolithic quotients in soluble groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a finite soluble group. Is it true that if $K$$\vartriangleleft$ $G$ is maximal respect to the condition $G$/$K$ non abelian, then this quotient is monolithic with monolith the derived subgroup? If it's true, is this difficult to prove? Thank you very much in advance to everyone!

Comment: Yes it's true and it is not difficult to prove.

Comment: @Derek may I have an hint for the proof? Thank you very much.

Comment: Since we are working in $G/K$ we may as well assume that $K=1$ and all proper quotients of $G$ are abelian. Let $N$ be minimal norma in $G$. Then $G/N$ is abelian so $[G,G] \le N$ and then $[G,G]=N$ by minimality.

Comment: @Derek thank you very much. You've been very kind.

Comment: @Derek excuse me again for the bother: how is used the hypothesis of solvability? Thank you.

Comment: It is not  used.